# My task convert lwIP from C into C++

Tags: c++, c, lwip

I got the task to rewrite the library  lwIP to OOP style, taking as an object stream, I began to understand, to climb into this library, but that's the problem:
src\include\lwip\arch.h  include file cc.h (line 43) which can not find neither I nor the compiler

Comment: What is your question, exactly ?

Answer (score 2):

cc.h is part of the OS emulation layer, this is one of the file you need to port lwip to your particular operating system.
[Porting lwip](http://lwip.wikia.com/wiki/Porting_for_an_OS)

If you want to see what it looks like, you should download an OS like freeRTOS, i think.